# How to generate correct frequency in DDS using stm32?

Tags: pll, dds

I had asked a question a week ago regarding DDS on STM32 and I got some good answers. Based on that I tried to write a code to implement DDS on stm32.
In my project I need to generate a 10 KHz sine wave. I have a stm32-nucleo G071RB which has maximum clock frequency as 64 MHz. I have a LUT of size, NS = 256.

Based on the calculation, I took PSC = 0, ARR = 25-1,

$$f_{trig} = \frac{F_{clk}}{(PSC+1)(ARR+1)}$$
$$F_o = \frac{f_{trig}}{NS}$$
I should be getting, $$F_o= 10KHz$$

[image: pin configuration]

```
/* USER CODE BEGIN Header */
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * @file           : main.c
  * @brief          : Main program body
  ******************************************************************************
  * @attention
  *
  * Copyright (c) 2023 STMicroelectronics.
  * All rights reserved.
  *
  * This software is licensed under terms that can be found in the LICENSE file
  * in the root directory of this software component.
  * If no LICENSE file comes with this software, it is provided AS-IS.
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */
/* USER CODE END Header */
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"

/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */
#include "math.h"
/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */

/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */
#define PI 3.14159
#define NS 256  //size of LUT
/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
DAC_HandleTypeDef hdac1;

TIM_HandleTypeDef htim16;

UART_HandleTypeDef huart2;

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */
uint32_t Fs = 64*pow(10,6);   //clock freq
int16_t f_exp = 10000; //desired freq
//double f_o = 0.0;
uint64_t tuning = 0;  //phase increment in phase accumulator part
int16_t idx = 0;   //counter
//int res = 12;
int16_t output_val = 0; //output value of sinewave
uint64_t phase = 0;
uint32_t LUT[NS];
/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void);
static void MX_TIM16_Init(void);
static void MX_DAC1_Init(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* LUT */

void sine_val(){
    for(int i = 0;i < NS;i++){
        LUT[i] = (sin(i*2* PI/NS)+1)*(4095/2);
    }
}
/*phase increment*/
void phase_increment(int16_t freq_out, uint32_t Fs, uint8_t acc_depth) {
    tuning = (round(freq_out * pow(2, acc_depth) /  Fs));
}

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_USART2_UART_Init();
  MX_TIM16_Init();
  MX_DAC1_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

  sine_val();
  HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT(&htim16);



  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */

  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage
  */
  HAL_PWREx_ControlVoltageScaling(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1);

  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIDiv = RCC_HSI_DIV1;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = RCC_HSICALIBRATION_DEFAULT;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = RCC_PLLM_DIV1;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 8;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = RCC_PLLQ_DIV2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLR = RCC_PLLR_DIV2;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

/**
  * @brief DAC1 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_DAC1_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN DAC1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END DAC1_Init 0 */

  DAC_ChannelConfTypeDef sConfig = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN DAC1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END DAC1_Init 1 */

  /** DAC Initialization
  */
  hdac1.Instance = DAC1;
  if (HAL_DAC_Init(&hdac1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** DAC channel OUT1 config
  */
  sConfig.DAC_SampleAndHold = DAC_SAMPLEANDHOLD_DISABLE;
  sConfig.DAC_Trigger = DAC_TRIGGER_NONE;
  sConfig.DAC_OutputBuffer = DAC_OUTPUTBUFFER_ENABLE;
  sConfig.DAC_ConnectOnChipPeripheral = DAC_CHIPCONNECT_DISABLE;
  sConfig.DAC_UserTrimming = DAC_TRIMMING_FACTORY;
  if (HAL_DAC_ConfigChannel(&hdac1, &sConfig, DAC_CHANNEL_1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN DAC1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END DAC1_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief TIM16 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_TIM16_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM16_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM16_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM16_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM16_Init 1 */
  htim16.Instance = TIM16;
  htim16.Init.Prescaler = 0;
  htim16.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim16.Init.Period = 25-1;
  htim16.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim16.Init.RepetitionCounter = 0;
  htim16.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim16) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM16_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM16_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief USART2 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 1 */
  huart2.Instance = USART2;
  huart2.Init.BaudRate = 115200;
  huart2.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart2.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart2.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart2.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart2.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart2.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  huart2.Init.OneBitSampling = UART_ONE_BIT_SAMPLE_DISABLE;
  huart2.Init.ClockPrescaler = UART_PRESCALER_DIV1;
  huart2.AdvancedInit.AdvFeatureInit = UART_ADVFEATURE_NO_INIT;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_UARTEx_SetTxFifoThreshold(&huart2, UART_TXFIFO_THRESHOLD_1_8) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_UARTEx_SetRxFifoThreshold(&huart2, UART_RXFIFO_THRESHOLD_1_8) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_UARTEx_DisableFifoMode(&huart2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief GPIO Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOF_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LED_GREEN_GPIO_Port, LED_GREEN_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : LED_GREEN_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = LED_GREEN_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_HIGH;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(LED_GREEN_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */
void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim)
{

  // Check which version of the timer triggered this callback and toggle LED
  if (htim == &htim16 )
  {
         HAL_DAC_Start(&hdac1, DAC_CHANNEL_1);

      //need to update the phase increment
      // Update the phase accumulator value by adding the phase increment value
         phase_increment(f_exp, Fs, 32); 
         phase += tuning;
         idx = (phase >> 24) & 0xFF ;  //to get 8 bit of phase values
      if (idx >= (float)NS)    // handle wraparound
      { idx = 0;
        }

      output_val = LUT[idx];
      HAL_DAC_SetValue(&hdac1, DAC_CHANNEL_1, DAC_ALIGN_12B_R, output_val);

}
}
/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @retval None
  */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
  __disable_irq();
  while (1)
  {
  }
  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */
```

However, I am getting this output and the frequency doesn't match.
[image: output]
[image: clock config]
How do i solve this? Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you add a picture of the Clock Configuration?

Comment: i have updated in the post.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a 10kHz sine wave and you change the DAC value once every interrupt and you have 256 DAC values within a period, then the TIMER frequency should be 2560000Hz. For this the CP value must be 25 and not 24.

With that, Interruption Frequency = 64MHz/25 = 2560000Hz.

[image]

Remember to enable interrupt.

[image]

Comment: Oh yes, i later might have changed to 25-1 but the problem is with the output value. The frequency is in mHz.

Comment: i must have done something wrong with the values. for phase_increment(), the Fs is it equal to interrupt frequency or the system clock (64MHz)??

Comment: Looking at your code the FS value should be 2560KHz. Another thing, don't use pow() function; when declaring your variable, it consumes space unnecessarily, your variable is already 32bits.